# Rails ActiveResource detecting a HTTP 206 response code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, activeresource

How can I detect that an active resource `find()` call returned HTTP 206 instead of a typical HTTP 200?

I know ActiveResource throws various exceptions for HTTP 3xx-5xx response codes, but how can you figure out what 200-level response code you received?

Comment: https://github.com/Fivell/activeresource-response try this gem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Active Resource responses, how to get them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972429/active-resource-responses-how-to-get-them) for how to get the last response for the thread.  You can then test the response code as needed:

```
class MyConn < ActiveResource::Connection
  def handle_response(resp)
    # Store in thread (thanks fivell for the tip).
    # Use a symbol to avoid generating multiple string instances.
    Thread.current[:active_resource_connection_last_response] = resp
    super
  end
  # this is only a convenience method. You can access this directly from the current thread.
  def last_resp
    Thread.current[:active_resource_connection_last_response]
  end
end

class MyResource < ActiveResource::Base
  class << self
    attr_writer :connection
  end
end

myconn = MyConn.new MyResource.connection.site
MyResource.connection = myconn  # replace with our enhanced version
object = MyResource.find(id)
response_code = MyResource.last_resp.code
```

Comment: Trying this out now. I'm disappointed that this is what it takes to get a simple response code. :(

Comment: It seems that connection= doesn't exist on the ActiveResource class. Any idea?

Comment: So I added `self.connection=(value); @connection = value; end` to fix this issue.

Comment: You're right, I missed the attribute writer necessary to expose the connection instance variable.  Updated.